# What does the phrase "while holding down one paddle" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from a rowing game app:

> It is not possible to turn in air, so take jumps in a straight line
>   **while holding down one paddle** if you have to turn abruptly while landing.

I am confused about the meaning of the phrase **while holding down one paddle**. Does the phrase mean to leave the paddle in place or does it mean to point it downward?

Comment: It perhaps means a [double-ended paddle](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-0i7tib7y/images/stencil/500x659/products/11372/5056/5236-2__15660.1414541875.jpg?c=2), and you point one end towards the water to get purchase to turn as soon as you land.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it's a double-ended paddle. Things are much clearer now.

Comment: @Bilkokuya Unfortunately, I cannot share the source due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: ...and presumably the idea is so that you can turn by applying pressure against the water at the soonest possible moment, before even landing.

Comment: I can't even tell if this is from a video game, or a game people play in kayaks on a river. If you can't provide additional information, I don't see how you expect the community to tell you what these odd phrases mean.

Comment: @J.R. I should have mentioned that it is game app. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it is describing a way of steering a paddle board.As they say, "It is not possible to turn in air" but if you push one end of the paddle (presumably double ended) into the water whilst in the air you can swing round it rather like a pole dancer can swing round a pole when their feet are off the ground.

Answer (score 0):

**To hold down** - If you hold someone down, you keep them under control and do not allow them to have much freedom or power or many [Def.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-down)

In the context above, it means you need to hold the padding in place I think.